# YouTube - What effect does the scheduledStartTime have?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a `LiveBroadcast` and have added a `scheduledStartTime` in the future. As far as I can tell from testing this time doesn't have an effect on the overall state of the `LiveBroadcast` i.e. if the broadcast has a lifeCycleState of ready/testing it does not transition to live at the time set as the `scheduledStartTime`.

Can anyone tell me what effect the `scheduledStartTime` has on the Live Broadcast (or any other entity?)

Cheers

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer from the official docs, in [file resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource):

> **snippet.scheduledStartTime**  *datetime* The date and time that the
>   broadcast is scheduled to start. The value is specified in ISO 8601
>   (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

Comment: I was looking at this too but it doesn't really describe what it does. From my experimenting it seems like the `scheduledStartTime` has no real effect on a `LiveBroadcast` (and does nothing apart from allow a user to be notified). Its such a shame that the documentation is so light and un-descriptive.